# How to copy a regular expression matched in notepad++ and the inverse selection of it

Tags: regex, notepad++, clipboard, copy-paste

[Example for Context](https://superuser.com/questions/820361/notepad-how-to-copy-the-text-only-which-matches-the-regex-expression-not-th)

How do you search for the first two characters in every row, select them and then copy them, in NotePad++?

Vice verse = Find everything **NOT** the first two characters, select them and be able to to cut/copy them.

The specific goal is to auto select the matching regex result so that the found text can be copied to the clip board.  NotePad++, to my knowledge, is only able to "Mark" the results found (apply slightly different coloration for visual distinction)- this to me seems counter intuitive not to be able to also "Select" the results found.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

In the following list:
`09 - ExtraCare Stockpiler`
`01 - Food & Family Loyalist`
`04 - ExtraCare Enthusiast`
`09 - ExtraCare Stockpiler`

The regex should return:
`09`
`01`
`04`
`09`

**INVERTED**

The same list should return:
`- ExtraCare Stockpiler`
`- Food & Family Loyalist`
`- ExtraCare Enthusiast`
`- ExtraCare Stockpiler`

Once the above is sorted out, what is the method to **select** the results so that they can be copied to the clipboard.
Note: Block selection (ALT + Click drag) is not an option because there are 180,000+ rows.

Comment: It's not clear what yo are asking. What exactly do you want to match? Please show some examples of what should, and should not, match. And please edit your question to be only *one* question (ask *another* question if you have two questions - this is not a chat room).

Comment: Updated question text for clarity.  Just like a light switch is on or off. I wanted a regex that inverts what your searching for, select it and be able to delete/copy/etc.

Comment: if just that you want to copy first two characters then you can do so using regular expressions: in find box keep (^..).*  and replace it with \1

Comment: on the other hand you can select the reverse .. in find box keep ^..(.*) and replace it with \1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I would do this is as follows.

Use a regular expression replace to keep the wanted characters and to delete the unwanted characters. Copy the entire buffer that now contains only the wanted characters and paste into the destination. Then either "undo" the edit replace or reload the file (menu => File => Reload from disc) or just discard the buffer. A minor variation is to: copy the whole of the original buffer, or just the relevant section, into a temporary buffer; do the replacement; copy; paste; then discard the temporary buffer.

To keep only the first two characters of each line of a buffer: Replace `^(..).*$` with `\1`. To keep everything except the first two characters of each line of a buffer: Replace `^..(.*)$` with `\1`. In both cases ensure that ". matches newline" is not selected.

The question is not precise on how lines with zero, one or two characters should be processed. The replacements in the previous paragraph will not alter or delete those lines. Hence it may be necessary to precede the above replacements with something to filter out the short lines.

Comment: The solution you provided worked perfectly. Thank you. As far as the steps you outlined, I was already doing that by utilizing Excel, so the methodology is great.  Regarding the zero, one or two characters... feel free to edit your response to include an example for all of those scenarios should someone else in the future happen upon this queston.